When to think of $A\in$Ob(C) as sets and when as proper classes?
I have always wondered about objects being either sets or classes considering categories. If I have a category C, meaning that we have the classes of objects Ob(C) and morphisms Mor(C). They are either themselves proper classes meaning C is a large category or they are sets meaning C is small. If for $A,B\in$Ob(C) the Hom(A,B) is a set we say C is locally small. That is what I understood.
But now I am confused about the definition of class and sets. In Gödel-
Bernays theory we say that: a class B is a set $\iff$ B is contained in another class.
But if all objects are contained in Ob(C) are they by that means sets? As I know from my courses we can´t always think of $A\in$Ob(C) as a set, we dont have a necessary presentation of the elements and have to think of abstract arguments as universal characteristics.
So in one sentence: When can I think of $A\in$Ob(C) as a set and when I cannot assume that.

The objects of the category of sets are sets. The objects of most categories are not sets. Many categories have objects that have a notion of underlying set: see concrete category.

I guess the statement "A class $B$ is a set iff $B$ is contained in another class" assumes on both sides that $B$ is a class already. This just states which classes are the ones we call sets. Since you don't usually think of an object as a class the equivalence does not apply there. That would be my interpretation. Take this with a grain of salt since I usually don't deal with set theory.

Yeah, my point is that I am lost  with what we call sets and classes and when to differ between both. From a small category, which means that Ob(C) and Mor(C) are themselves sets, we know that A$\in$ Ob(C) is a set, is this by definition or how to understand this based upon certain conceptions.

Are you asking specifically about the encoding details of category theory in set-theoretical foundations? It is good to keep in mind that such details are completely inessential to the field of category theory, which can (one might say should) be formalised in other foundations such as type theory. But to answer your question, an element of a set is a set, because the relationship "being an element of" formally only applies to sets.

I think that answers my question. I was just confused, because in some proves we can consider certain objects to be sets and in some proves we cannot asume that. But I think that explains it. So for small categories we have that A$\in$ Ob(C) is a set due to Ob(C) being a set.

Or am I wrong about that?

I mean, sure, in the same sense that $42$ is a set in ZFC set theory. Everything you can talk about within the theory is a set.

You've pretty much cleared this up in the comments, I think, but to emphasize: in standard Gödel-Bernays class/set theory, where everything in existence is either a set or a class of sets, then yes, the objects of any category must always "be" sets, ontologically. But for categories that aren't the actual category of sets and functions, we will generally think of such objects, psychologically, as "being" something other than sets, such as topological spaces or formulas in a language or semantically vacuous labels or literal dots. In other foundations, there is no need for something like a topological space to fundamentally be a set, though it will always be associated to its set of points, and in that case the objects of a category need not be sets.
